# How to set a property in User based on another model? [ django ]

Tags: django, django-models

- custom User have `feedbackscore` which calculates this way `((positive-negative)+neutral)/(positive+negative+neutral)*100`
- there is feedback app where everyone can give a single feedback to each `User`

What is the most convenient way to approach this problem, I do need to store it in User because some functions will be limited to users with a good score. So how should I archive this?

- should I do a Manager?
- should I set a Property?
- anything else?

Comment: Property sounds reasonable.

Comment: @dfundako Any idea how to archive that, because I have no idea. Like I can do for a single record, but how do I do it for many records?

Comment: You don't need to store feedbackscore because it is nothing but a calculation of 3 other fields. If you only need feedbackscore as it is right now, don't archive those three values and calculate it on the fly. If you will need to see what someone's feedbackscore was a year ago, you store those historical records in the database.